# Compare Id's of an array in twig

Tags: arrays, twig, compare

I'm currently comparing two array's and their id's. If they match it should output a count value. It is totally working but I'm thing if there is another way in doing this rather than:

```html
{% for count in product_count %}
  {% if count.term_id == child._menu_item_object_id %}
    {{ count.count }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for any support! :)

Comment: `{% for count in product_count if count.term_id == child._menu_item_object_id %}`

Comment: Great Thanks! :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DarkBee

```
{% for count in product_count if count.term_id == child._menu_item_object_id %}
```